# How to get dict key for matching value in unique values?

Tags: python, dictionary

A pretty basic question, but was really unable to find it on the Internet...
What's the most pythonic way to get the key that belongs to a list of values of which the input arg is an element?

I am under the impression that `dict` might not be the right type. Reason why I would chose it is that both all keys and all values are unique. --> It's a form of "unique alias mapping", which is why the inversion value -> key should work.

```
my_dict = {
    'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'key2': ['d', 'e'],
    'key3': ['f'],
    'key4': 'g'
}

identifier = 'a'

# Desired output: the following functional call works
my_dict.get_key_from_value_in_value_list(identifier)
'key1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you stated, all the values are unique you can create an inverse dictionary and use this for lookup:

```py
my_dict = {"key1": ["a", "b", "c"], "key2": ["d", "e"], "key3": ["f"], "key4": "g"}

inv_dict = {v: k for k, l in my_dict.items() for v in l}
print(inv_dict['a'])
```

Prints:

```
key1
```

Comment: Genius! And with the right assertion in place, it's also a perfect 'inline validator' for the key assumption of uniqueness!

Comment: For completeness, a valid assertion would be `assert len(my_dict.values()) == len(set(my_dict.values())), 'Dict values are not unique'`

Comment: I'm afraid that's not right... the alias maps to lists so you can't build a `set` of `my_dict.values()`, which may be a combination of lists and strs

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the "most pythonic way" but maybe it will inspire someone else.

```py
idx = tuple(my_dict.values()).index(identifier)
desired_key = tuple(my_dict.items())[idx][0]
```

Comment: `tuple(my_dict.values())` will look like `(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], g)`. So for example, `tuple(my_dict.values()).index('b')` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Slothrop pointed out the error in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76112626/20948146). I've worked out the correct way to use `items()`:

```py
desired_key = next(k for k,v in my_dict.items() if identifier in v)
```

`next()` chooses the first item in the generator which means this returns the first key containing the identifier if there are multiple.